# ListView ItemsSource binding not displaying items

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a bound ListView in Xamarin. Here's the C# code:

```
public partial class LearnPage : ContentPage
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    //ObservableCollection<TodoItem> Items = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
    private IEnumerable<TodoItem> _items;
    public IEnumerable<TodoItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_items, value))
                return;
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public LearnPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Items = new TodoItem[]{
            new TodoItem{ DisplayName = "Milk cartons are recyclable" }
        };
        //Items.Add(new TodoItem { DisplayName = "Milk cartons are recyclable" });
    }
}
```

You can also see some commented out code with an `ObervableCollection`, which I have also tried with.

And here's the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="learn.LearnPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,10,0,10">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowHeight="40" x:Name="sarasas">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

When I build the app, an empty list is displayed. I'm really new to Xamarin and I think I'm just missing something obvious. Any help appreciated!

Comment: This has happened to me and I tried assigning to list n different way try this: var list = new TodoItem[]{
            new TodoItem{ DisplayName = "Milk cartons are recyclable" }
        };    Items = list; See if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if ContentPage uses `[CallerMemberName]` for the `OnPropertyChanged()` method. So first thing I would try is to write `OnPropertyChanged("Items")` instead.

Either way, if I were you I would separate concerns and move the Items into a `ViewModel` class, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` itself. This will help later on if you want to test, add more code such as commands, inject dependencies etc., where you will keep ViewModel code separate from View code.

So you could start with:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then create your ViewModel:

```
public class LearnViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();

    private ICommand _addTodoItem;
    public ICommand AddTodoItem => 
        _addTodoItem = _addTodoItem ?? new Command(DoAddTodoItem);

    private int _count;
    private void DoAddTodoItem()
    {
        var item = new TodoItem { DisplayName = $"Item {++_count}" };
        // NotifyCollectionChanged must happen on UI thread.
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
             Items.Add(item);
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can keep your View code thin like:

```
public partial class LearnPage : ContentPage
{
    public LearnPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new LearnViewModel();
    }
}
```

Normally you would invoke a command to populate the `Items` in your ViewModel, this could be by fetching data from the Internet, or loading local data from a database etc.

In this sample you can just add a constructor to the `LearnViewModel` and call `DoAddTodoItem` a couple of times:

```
public class LearnViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public LearnViewModel()
    {
        DoAddTodoItem();
        DoAddTodoItem();
    }
    ...
```

This should show you something like this when you launch the app:

[image]

Comment: It uses `[CallerMemberName]` https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs#L133

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very elaborate. I'll have to spend some time understanding this - as there's some unknown syntax and tricks as well. I'll get back to you if I have more questions or can't get it working!